# Follow-up Reminder alert using mimeMessage Java

Tags: java, outlook, mime

I have used a below code to generate automatic mail with followup flag- reminder as how we do in outlook. But the problem is I'm not getting the alert which the reminder property usually pop up in outlook. Once the mail triggered, I checked the mail which shows like reminder is set up good. What may be the problem for not getting the alert?

```
final long REPLY_BY_MS = 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L; //One day.
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setHeader("X-Message-Flag", "Follow up");
javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat md 
        = new javax.mail.internet.MailDateFormat();
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
msg.setHeader("Reply-By", md.format(new Date(now + REPLY_BY_MS)));
msg.setSentDate(new Date(now));
```